# Tree structure in R

Tags: r, tree

Is there a package that implements a tree structure in R ? Every node can have multiple childs (so it's not a binary tree).

Comment: A list would probably do. See `?list`.

Comment: Would this help? `stats::dendrogram`

Comment: You asked for a package so I won't make this an answer — but for future googlers (like me): `environment`s are a naturally occurring data-structure in R with which you can build your own trees.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the data.tree package, which you can get from [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/index.html) or from [github](https://github.com/gluc/data.tree). It lets you build and modify a tree, and implements tree traversal out of the box. And as a side note to isomorphismes: Indeed, it is implemented using environments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this function:
[dendrogram](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/dendrogram.html)

Answer (score 0):

`data.tree` is what you are looking for.

This is a good starting point:

**Introduction to data.tree**

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#trees